# Executed drop table accidently

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Need a help badly.

I accidentally dropped one table from my database. There is a backup of the db but it is of 15 days before.

Can someone tell me if I can get my table data by any means?

Thanks

Comment: See this for recovering data from transaction logs http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic456434-357-1.aspx

Comment: What recovery model is the database in?

Comment: How do you *accidentally* execute a `DROP TABLE` command? If you didn't mean to do it you shouldn't be writing it in the first place.

Comment: Do you miss data for 15 days from last backup, is it correct?

Comment: Just tell me why `Upvotes` ?

Answer (score 2):

Before you do anything, make a copy of your current data and tran logs.

I never had this problem myself, by I know some people that swear by the ApexSql recovery tools -- not cheap, but can be worth it if other methods don't work for you.

Answer (score 1):

Speaking of DROP table and ApexSQL tools, you can reffer to the **[4 techniques for recovering lost tables due to DROP Table operation](http://solutioncenter.apexsql.com/4-techniques-for-recovering-lost-tables-due-to-drop-table-operation/)** online article for more details and methods that can be used

Disclaimer: I work as a Product Support Engineer at ApexSQL

Answer (score 0):

1. Take a backup of your existing database.
2. Restore database from **YOUR 15 DAYS OLD** backup, but as NEW DATABASE (under new name).
3. Fetch create script for the table.
4. Create table in your current database.
5. Use SELECT... INTO... to transfer data from one database to the other.

Comment: How can they SELECT INTO from something that doesn't exist any more?

Comment: Pretty sure they're asking if there's a way to get the data from the last 15 days (i.e. the changes made after the last backup) rather than how to restore a single table from a full database backup.

Answer (score 0):

If you backup your database and logs now (assuming you haven't truncated/shrunk them) then you could restore this backup to a point in time just before you dropped the table.  See this technet article:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179451(v=sql.100).aspx

Just make sure you do not overwrite your older backup, as if you can't restore it to that point in time, then you may need to use the older one like other answers have stated.

Additionally, ensure you restore it to a NEW database name and rename it after you are satisfied the data is back to how it should be.